# Fill DataGridView with data from SQL

Tags: vb.net, oledb

I want to fill a DataGridView with data returned from a SQL.  So here is my code *[I provided cause some people may think I'm asking for help before trying myself]*

I want the DataGridView to be filled by a data from SQL not to show all the records.

The SQL **"Select * From books where title='php%' Order By Title;"**

## useless code :(   :'(   :<

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Public Class frmMain
 Dim connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Database.mdb;Persist" & " Security Info=True"

 Private Sub frmMain_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
  Me.BooksTableAdapter.Fill(Me.TblBooks.books)
 End Sub

  Private Sub txtTerm_TextChanged() Handles txtTerm.TextChanged
   If Trim(txtTerm.Text) = "" Then Exit Sub

   Dim tblCustomBooks As New DataTable
   Dim adpBooks As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("Select * From books where title='php%' Order By Title", _
  '"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Database.mdb;Persist" & " Security Info=True")
   adpBooks.Fill(tblCustomBooks)
   BooksTableAdapter.Fill(tblCustomBooks)
  'Dim myConnection As SqlConnection
  'Dim myCommand As SqlDataAdapter
  'myConnection = New SqlConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Database.mdb;Persist" & " Security Info=True")
  'myCommand = New SqlDataAdapter("Select * From books where title='php%' Order By Title", myConnection)
  'Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet()
  'myCommand.Fill(ds)
  'gridTable.DataSource = ds
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you've tried a number of different things, but it's not apparent from your code what order you tried them in.  Based on the current version of your code, you're missing two things:

First, an OleDBConnection object to use with the OleDbDataAdapter.

Second, you're not assigning anything to the `DataGridView`s DataSource property, so nothing will show up.

Also, you appear to be using two different OleDbDataAdapters (or maybe two different DataAdapters altogether) to fill `tblCustomBooks`, so depending on what `BooksTableAdapter` is set up as may also be causing you problems.

Try this:

```
Private Sub txtTerm_TextChanged() Handles txtTerm.Changed

    If Trim(txtTerm.Text) = "" Then Exit Sub

    Dim tblCustomBooks As New DataTable

    Using conn As New OleDbConnection(connectionString)
        Dim adpBooks As New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM books WHERE title = 'php%' ORDER BY title", conn)
        adpBooks.Fill(tblCustomBooks)

        gridTable.DataSource = tblCustomBooks
    End Using
End Sub
```

See:

[DataGridView.DataSource Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.datasource.aspx)

[OleDbDataAdapter Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbdataadapter%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

In your SQL statement try [WHERE Title LIKE 'php%'] instead of [WHERE Title = 'php%'].

I've run into similar problems with MS SQL and this was the fix. I'm not sure if the SQL syntax is the same for the Jet provider, but it's worth a try at least.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

```
dim dt as new datatable
'i already maked the class and now load from a database
dt=cls.getdata("select * from tblinf")
datagridview1.datasource=dt
```